# Can't boot into windows months after install Kali on a partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, grub, kali-linux

A few months ago I installed Kali and GRUB using this tutorial, http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows and it's been great, but recently after about two weeks of not using windows I tried to boot into it and I ran into some issues. When I power on the computer and select windows 7 from the GRUB OS select screen, I am greeted with the screen:

> Windows error Recovery
>
> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be
>   the cause.
>
> If windows files have been damaged or configured incorrectly, Startup
>   Repair can help diagnose and fix the problem. If power was interuptted
>   during startup, choose Start Windows Normally.
>
> *(Use the arrow keys to highlight your choice.)*
>
> - Launch Startup Repair (recommended)
> - Start Windows Normally
>
> ENTER=CHOOSE

so I choose the first option, and after a few seconds of "Windows is loading files...", I get the screen

> Windows Boot Manager
>
> Windows has encountered a problem communicating with a device
>   connected to your computer (I assume this is my hard drive as I don't
>   have any external drives connected).
>
> This error can be caused by unplugging a removeable storage device
>   such as an external USB drive while the device is in use, or by faulty
>   hardware such as a hard drive or CD-ROM drive that is failing. Make
>   sure any removable storage is properly connected and then restart your
>   computer.
>
> If you continue to receive this error message, contact the hardware
>   manufacturer
>
> - Status: 0xc00000e9
> - Info: An unexpected I/O error has occurred
>
> ENTER=Continue ESC=Exit

also, when I choose the other option, Start Windows Normally I get the same message.

I am pretty sure this is caused by me cutting power to my laptop when it froze a few days ago while in Kali, but the catch is that I don't have the original CD or serial to restore windows, so I need alternate solutions.

As a side note, none of the files on the drive really matter to me, I just need to keep the BIOS partition. I'll be tracking this post pretty often, and I'll post the outputs of any commands or actions that anyone needs as soon as I can.

EDIT: I ran diagnostics from the f12 menu and immediately got an error code about the hard drive: 0146 2000-0146
EDIT: I don't know if this means anything, but I went into gparted and I saw that the windows partition has a yellow exclamation point next to it:

[image]

MAJOR EDIT: Now I really screwed stuff up, I somehow modified the MBR and now it won't give me the GRUB os select screen.

Comment: The first thing to try is to rebuild grub ( `update-grub` on Ubuntu - I don't know if it's the same on Kali). If it's recent hardware with Windows pre-installed, the serial number may be embedded in the BIOS, in which case you won't need it to re-install. If you know the edition (Home, etc), then you should be able to repair from any install disc for the same edition. Finally, you could try a Windows 10 upgrade from a bootable disc (and downgrade again, if you really need to keep W7).

Comment: @AFH `update-grub` ran but didn't do anything, the computer came with vista, but I installed drivers. It's an old Dell XPS 13. I'll keep the windows 10 upgrade in mind, but I'd like to hear a few more alternatives first.